# how to refactor all 3 http operations (GET, PUT, DELETE) under one path in OpenAPI

Tags: http, openapi

I want to regroup my all 4 http operations (GET, PUT, DELETE, POST) in separate .yaml files like the following :

```
paths:
  /v0/helloworld/users:
    post:
      $ref: "./paths/users/createUser.yaml"

  /v0/helloworld/users/{id}:
    parameters:
      - name: id
        in: path
        description: The ID of the User
        required: true
        schema:
          type: integer
    put:
      $ref: "./paths/users/updateUser.yaml"
    delete:
      $ref: "./paths/users/deleteUser.yaml"
    get:
      $ref: "./paths/users/getUser.yaml"
```

However OpenApi parser throws a syntactic error saying that $ref is not allowed where it is right now :

```
Errors: 
        -attribute paths.'/v0/helloworld/users/{id}'(delete).$ref is unexpected
        -attribute paths.'/v0/helloworld/users/{id}'(delete).responses is missing
        -attribute paths.'/v0/helloworld/users'(post).$ref is unexpected
        -attribute paths.'/v0/helloworld/users'(post).responses is missing
        -attribute paths.'/v0/helloworld/users/{id}'(put).$ref is unexpected
        -attribute paths.'/v0/helloworld/users/{id}'(put).responses is missing
        -attribute paths.'/v0/helloworld/users/{id}'(get).responses is missing
        -attribute paths.'/v0/helloworld/users/{id}'(get).$ref is unexpected
```

I don't want to fold all plain code of each operation to finish with a huge spec file. I want to rather to refactor these operations in a more readable and understandable .yaml files. For instance my ./paths/users/deleteUser.yaml looks like this :

```
delete:
  summary: Delete s User by ID
  operationId: deleteUser
  tags:
    - users
  parameters:
    - in: path
      name: id
      required: true
      description: ID of the User to delete
      schema:
        type: integer
  responses:
    '200':
      description: Successful operation
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            "$ref": "../../schemas/SuccessDTO.yaml"
    '404':
      description: User not found
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            "$ref": "../../schemas/ErrorDTO.yaml"
```

Is there a way to fix this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which of the OpenAPI tools you're using but you can definitely use multiple files rather than one big one. I use [Redocly CLI](https://github.com/redocly/redocly-cli) which has a `split` command to put things in different files (disclaimer: I work for Redocly! Other tools probably do something similar so check out the options with whatever you are already using). `redocly split` splits each path into a different file, containing all the verbs, so I can at least verify that you could do it that way.